# Show method only under certain conditions

Tags: c#, .net, object, methods

I created a .net extension method that converts an string to an integer and throws an InvalidCastException if the passed string isn't an integer:

```
public static int ToInt32(this String str)
    {
        int result;

        // string is not a valid 32 bit integer
        if (!Int32.TryParse(str, out result))
            throw new InvalidCastException();

        return result;
    }
```

Is it possible do don't show up / offer the method on the string object if it isn't an integer?

Comment: The short answer is no. the compiler will have no idea what is in a string at design time unless it is a literal, and even then there is no ability to reduce a methods visibility/accessibility based on that. Also this function as little value all things considered. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: And the code as is could just be replaced with `int.Parse`

Comment: The above code was just an example and int.Parse will throw Exceptions, too.
So i wondered if it would be possible to provide methods conditional :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible do don't show up / offer the method on the string object if it isn't an integer?

No. Even if the parameter were a literal, the C# language doesn't have a mechanism for restricting method overloads according to parameter values. And of course, there's no requirement you can make that the method argument be provided as a literal. A variable or other expression used to provide the argument could be literally *any* string, and the compiler has no way to identify the nature of the argument (i.e. check whether it could be parsed as an integer).

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might be able to solve the broader problem with a Roslyn code analyzer. That's a whole other "ball of wax" though.